# Sqlite exception when insert and update query executes for ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a Web API to connect to my sqlite database for a simple Winforms application. When I call `GET` method, it execute a select query and works fine.

When I call `POST` method, it executes an insert query and throws exception

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800007FF): unable to open database file. unable to open database file

It works fine when I test locally.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

This is for IIS - Amazon VPS

My database file is under `APP_DATA` directory with READ/WRITE permissions.

My connection string is

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|testdb.db;Version=3;Password=test123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give permission (`Modify` and `Write`) on the .db file to `App_Data` directory for `Application Pool` user for SQLite folder.

- `You should also make sure that the ASP.Net application identity is allowed read/write access to the` sqlite `folder created` under the root of your web app because data will be read as well as written to the database file under this folder.

  Just right click on the `sqlite` folder and select *Properties* and then the *Security* tab as in screen shot below. In most localhost cases, the ASP.Net identity is IIS_IUSRS which is highlighted below. Make sure that this user has full control over the sqlite folder.

[image]

Comment: could you please explain in brief? Because i am a newbie in IIS

Comment: Are you running from `localhost` or `IIS`?

Comment: what is the sqlite folder? Where it exist? I have database file inside app_data directory

Comment: Yes please provide access to `app_data` folder and inside the `.db` file

Comment: From you suggestion i have no sqlite folder under the root. I just copied testdb.db into app_data folder. I will modify app_data directory permissions and let you know

Comment: What i am referring sqllite folder here is `APP_Data`